# Sending a DM to a new member

Tags: discord.py

I'm working on a basic bot with discord.py and I need to figure out how to send a DM when a new member joins. When a new user joins, it should trigger an event which will get the member and send them a DM welcoming them to the server. I've tried quite a few variations of code trying to get it to work but nothing happens when I join with an alt.

Here's the basic code I have:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}! Welcome to the server!'
    )
```

I've also tried without the `member.create_dm()` because the docs said that it should do that on its own. I'm using Python 3.7.3 and discord.py 1.5.1 so old answers from a couple years ago don't work. I've tried everything that I can find.

Comment: It might be because some members have direct DMs turned off. In that case, they need to have you on their friend list for you to be able to send DMs to them.

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable `intents.members`, also I saw a handful of questions similar like these so you didn't do a good job when researching.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

# If you're using commands.Bot
bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
# If you're using discord.Client
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://www.discord.com/developers/applications)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with discord.py 1.5, in order to receive the member join event, you must enable the members gateway intent, which you can read about [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html). You must first enable to members intent on the developer portal, then when constructing your client/bot instance, you must pass your intents to it.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(**other_options, intents=intents)
# Or if using the clinet
client = discord.Client(**other_options, intents=intents)
```

Finally, you should also be sure to handle the Forbidden exception that may be raised if the member has their DMs turned off

```py
try:
    await member.send('Some text')
except discord.Forbidden:
    # The user had their DMs disabled, do whatever you need to
    # nothing in this case
    pass
```